# SharePoint: Webpart to show permissions for a list/document library

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, web-parts

Is there any webpart (free or purchased) that can be set to display the permissions for a list or document library? We want to set up pages that contain a view to a document Library and a section at the top of the page that lists what users can access the library, to ensure that users adding content to the library don't accidentally place it somewhere where the wrong people can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Access Checker Web Part](http://accesschecker.codeplex.com/)

It offers something that should be much easier out-of-the-box: list user's permissions throughout the site. I can testify it saved me *hours* of sharepoint permission debugging.

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=AccessChecker&DownloadId=43465](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=AccessChecker&DownloadId=43465)

Comment: That's useful for admins, but doesn't help the problem we have: users need to know what permissions a library has before putting documents in it.